# Running ST's in parallel with SPOCK

Tags: junit, spock

I am trying to run CT's in parallel with SPOCK, currently using Junit4.

I have tried migrating to JUnit 5 but none of the config for Parallelizing the tests seems to work.

I am working from this
guide https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/parallel_execution.html#parallel-execution

I am looking to find out is this even possible yet, there does not seem to be much resources on the topic.

Comment: By the way, what are CT's and ST's?

Comment: Component test's

Comment: It is very difficult to advise you in any meaningful way without further details. If would help tremendously if you could show your code and configuration, ideally as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. in a GitHub repository or gist. Thank you.